# Searching between two dates using sed on s3

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, sed

I am trying to get all files between two dates on s3 -

```
aws s3 ls 's3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/' --recursive |  sed  "/2018-06-01/,/`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'`/p"
```

It tends to give me all the data. Used this but it doesn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412898/2251058 (Doesn't filter anything) 
Is this a right way to do it.

Any help with it is appreciated.

**Updates**

As requested - RavinderSingh13

I used -n as and found without -n the sed command acts as cat command.

As suggested by jhnc I added -n to use as grep command and it gives me empty result

A sample input pattern is something as follows with empty result

```
2018-06-01 13:32:20      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
.
.
.
.
2019-02-04 00:13:12      12344 <filepath>....gz
```

With added -n (to use as grep) , I had a bug above where -n was not used , it doesn't show any output. To check I used the below commands. It gives no output.

```
echo "2018-01-01" |  sed -n "/2018-06-01/,/`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'`/p"
echo "2019-01-01" |  sed -n "/2018-06-01/,/`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'`/p"
echo "2019-02-01" |  sed -n "/2018-06-01/,/`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'`/p"
echo "2019-02-01" |  sed -n  "/2018-06-01/,/2019-01-05/p"
echo "2019-06-30" |  sed -n  "/2018-06-01/,/2019-01-05/p"
```

Comment: Please do mention output of command `aws s3 ls 's3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/' --recursive` and do mention expected sample output too as it is not clear.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added a sample output. Let me know if anything else is required . Basically I am using the date from aws s3 ls (listing of files) to grep

Comment: You might want to change `sed` to `sort | sed -n`. And I guess you know that you'll get only the first file of the end date. And for completeness, start each `//` with `^`

Comment: @jhnc The ls command is sorted in this case. I tried with `sed -n` it gives empty for both valid and invalid results  `echo "2018-08-30" |  sed -n  "/2018-06-01/,/\`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'\`/p" `  `echo "2018-06-30" |  sed -n  "/2018-06-01/,/\`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'\`/p" `

Comment: Just realised: this won't work if starting date doesn't appear in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` code given in the question will only work properly if the starting date appears in the list.

We need to do string comparisons rather than regexp matching. Either awk or perl is up to the job.

Fancy perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Usage: $0 date1 date2
# where dates can be anything supported by date(1)
# remember to "quote whitespace"

# fancy date parsing
open(my $cmd, '-|', 'date', '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '--date', $ARGV[0]||'1970-01-01') or die $!;
my $start = <$cmd>;
chomp $start;
close $cmd;
open(my $cmd, '-|', 'date', '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '--date', $ARGV[1]||'now') or die $!;
my $end = <$cmd>;
chomp $end;
close $cmd;

# start should be earlier than end
($start, $end) = ($end, $start) if $start gt $end;

while (<STDIN>) {
    print if $_ ge $start && $_ le $end;
}
```

Simple awk (could embed call date in the same way as original sed):

```
awk '$0>="2018-06-01" && $0<="2019-01-01" {print}'
```

Comment: Yes I did the same earlier , forgot to put it as an answer - `aws s3 ls 's3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/' --recursive  |  awk -v begintime='2018-06-01' -v endtime="\`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'\`" -v bucket="s3://big-data-analytics-prod/" '{if($1>=begintime && $1<=endtime) {print bucket $4} }'`

Comment: awk is better to use for this.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple (w/o sed) solution, please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: thiscommand startdate enddate
#    starddate and enddate should be in the format: yyyy-mm-dd

start=${1//-/}
end=${2//-/}

while read -r date rest; do
    date2=${date//-/}
    if ((start <= date2 && date2 <= end)); then
        echo "$date $rest"
    fi
done < input.txt
```

where the sample file `input.txt` looks like:

```
2018-06-01 13:32:20      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-01-01 01:23:45      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-01-30 00:22:45      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-02-01 11:03:05      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-02-02 02:24:55      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-02-04 00:13:12      12344 <filepath>....gz
```

Then invoke the script with:

```
$ ./thisscript 2019-01-01 2019-02-02
```

yields:

```
2019-01-01 01:23:45      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-01-30 00:22:45      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-02-01 11:03:05      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
2019-02-02 02:24:55      <filesize> <filepath>....gz
```

If you wish to process the output from the `aws` command directly, you can say:

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: thiscommand startdate enddate
#    starddate and enddate should be in the format: yyyy-mm-dd

start=${1//-/}
end=${2//-/}

while read -r date rest; do
    date2=${date//-/}
    if ((start <= date2 && date2 <= end)); then
        echo "$date $rest"
    fi
done < <(aws s3 ls 's3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/' --recursive)
```

You'll see there is no trick: it just converts the date format into a straight numbers and compares them arithmetically.

Comment: Nice. If we're using bash, the `s///` aren't needed as we can do `[ "$start" \< "$date2" ] && [ "$date2" \< "$end" ]` directly (although it will change the selected range unless we also test `=` which negates the character saving!)

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you for reminding me that we can perform dictionary-order comparison without dehyphening. I may have been caught in the concept to convert to numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I learnt a bit of awk and instead used awk to compute this but forgot to share as an answer.

```
endtime=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-30 day'`
begintime="2018-06-01"
bucket="s3://big-data-analytics-prod/"
path='s3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/'
aws s3 ls path --recursive  |  awk '{if($1>=$begintime && $1<=$endtime) {print $4} }'
```

OR in a line

```
aws s3 ls 's3://big-data-analytics-prod/LZ/copycat/emailstats/' --recursive  |  awk -v begintime="2018-06-01" -v endtime="`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '30 days ago'`"  '{if($1>=begintime && $1<=endtime) {print $4}}'
```